# How to remove Selectitem from f:selectitems using ADF?

Tags: jsf-2, oracle-adf

I want to remove Selectitem from f:selectitems using ADF and manage bean when click a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to clear selection

```
public BindingContainer getBindings() {
        return BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    }

    /**Method to Clear selected value of shuttle (Reset Shuttle)
     * @param actionEvent
     */
    public void resetShuttleAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        BindingContainer bc = this.getBindings();
        JUCtrlListBinding listBindings = (JUCtrlListBinding)bc.get("DepartmentsView1");
        listBindings.clearSelectedIndices();

    }
```

For details check - http://www.awasthiashish.com/2013/12/clear-selected-values-of-shuttle.html

Comment: Glad your issue is solved :) You can mark it as correct now

Comment: I marked it as correct and it realy the correct answer